# Why these rtm transactions act weird?

Tags: c, x86, intrinsics, intel-tsx

I am trying to work with rtm transactions. I started using intrinsics to implement a simple transaction. But I found out the following line always returns **zero**, while for the transaction to successfully begin, it should be **-1**:
`int status = _xbegin();`
Then, I tried putting the **if..else** in a loop to reach this code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<immintrin.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int status = _xbegin();
    if (status == _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
        printf("111");
        _xend();
    } else {
        printf("000");
    }
    status = _xbegin();
    if (status == _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
        printf("111");
        _xend();
    } else {
        printf("000");
    }
}
```

The output of the code is **"000111"** and I can't understand why the first transaction fails but the second one does not.
Also, if I make changes to printf inputs in the first transaction, the second transaction won't start at all and the output of the following modified code will be **"0000"**:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<immintrin.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int status = _xbegin();
    if (status == _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
        printf("111");
        _xend();
    } else {
        printf("0");
    }
    status = _xbegin();
    if (status == _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
        printf("111");
        _xend();
    } else {
        printf("000");
    }
}
```

The same happens if I remove one of the printf lines, too.

I want to understand why the outputs are like this and how to fix the problem?
Note that I use immintrin.h and compile using "gcc -mrtm".

Comment: What if you just save an integer status inside the transactional region, instead of putting `printf` inside the transaction?  You know `printf` is going to cause an abort before `_xend()` is ever reached, right?

Comment: I upvoted the question because I'm not sure exactly how the intrinsics are supposed to work: in asm the `xbegin` instruction takes a jump target as an operand, and jumps there (with all other changes to architectural state discarded) if the transaction aborts.

Comment: Possible guess: `printf` succeeds inside the transaction on the 2nd call because some required page-fault(s) already happened, so it actually does get as far as running a `syscall` instruction inside the transaction?

Comment: @PeterCordes It appears you are right. Maybe it is the page holding the strings that fault though.  GCC transforms the `printf("0")` into a `putchar` ([link](https://godbolt.org/g/VdpTSL)), preventing the first `else` branch from triggering another #PF that'd load the data page (the #PF generated by first `printf("111")` and that aborted the transaction is ignored by the CPU as per docs)